# problem with initializer: Property 'self.options' not initialized at super.init call

Tags: swift, cocoapods, initializer

i'm using [SwiftPageMenu](https://github.com/SonChanthem/SwiftPageMenu) from cocoapods. it used to work perfectly. but after i reinstall it by pod i keep getting this error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented

i looked for some solution and mostly advised to change :

```
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

to :

```
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

but i get

> Property 'self.options' not initialized at super.init call

options is initialized in other init functions:

```
   public init(options: PageMenuOptions? = nil) {
        self.options = options ?? DefaultPageMenuOption()
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }




    public init?(coder: NSCoder, options: PageMenuOptions? = nil) {
        self.options = options ?? DefaultPageMenuOption()
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
```

i didn't really understand the problem can someone help me please.

here's the [controller](https://github.com/SonChanthem/SwiftPageMenu/blob/master/Sources/PageMenuController.swift)

Comment: The error tells you that there is a property `options` which must be initialized **before** calling super. And your *controller* link is dead.

Comment: Yes, this error will be shown if any property is declared but not defined, with is the initialiser's scope, either assign some default value at the time of declaration or in the initialiser.

Comment: but it's initialized in other init functions

Comment: Link in the question is broken.

Comment: i fixed it right now :) @Kamran

Comment: Try this, `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   self.options = DefaultPageMenuOption()
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}`. Just initialize it with defaultPageMenuOptions.

Comment: It must be initialized in **all** implemented initializers.

Comment: @Kamran i tried it but it only takes the default setup when it used to work with custom ones :)

Comment: Yeah, this was just to let you run your code. Now, as shown in the file in link, you shouldn't use this method `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` to initialize the `PageMenuController` so change your initialization to use any one of other two initializers.

Comment: @Kamran okay i will try your solution and thank you very much

Comment: One of your view controller, which is not capable of being initialized through nib, may be set as a Custom Class in your storyboard (or xib). Check the storyboard settings.